# paypal IPN php script

Tags: php, paypal, handler, paypal-ipn

I just realized that my paypal ipn handler in php doesn't work anymore (and I change nothing), I  use [the sample php script provided by paypal.](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/FR/fr_FR/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt)

I tried to isolate the problem by making several test, and at this time I can say that the problem is not the "VERIFIED" or the "INVALID" thing but comes from these lines:

[...]

```
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
        // check the payment_status is Completed
```

[...]

Anyone know if paypal change something or why it doesn't work?

thanks'

ps: if I put my code before all the paypal tests (before the line "if (!$fp)") it just works fine

This is my code, I comment where the "database process" works and where it doesn't.

```
<?php

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];


// DATABASE PROCESS WORKS (BEFORE THE PAYPAL TESTS)



if (!$fp)
{
    // HTTP ERROR
}
else
   {

// DATABASE PROCESS WORKS

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
        {
            // check the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment


// DATABASE PROCESS NOT WORKING

        }
        else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
        {
            // log for manual investigation

// DATABASE PROCESS NOT WORKING
        }
    }
fclose ($fp);
}

?>
```

Comment: have you check error_log about this problem ?

Comment: How can I check error_log please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the updated script on x.xom
https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4

it uses CURL instead of fsock

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when server not configured properly for socket or openSSL module not configured.

OR

You can try with below code  sample of using file_get_contents instead of $fp code

```
<?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// for live mode
$url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
// for developement mode
$url="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

// instead of use of fopen you can use
$res=file_get_contents($url"?".$req);
// compare response
if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment
}
else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation
}

?>
```

if file_get_contents not working then you can use CURL for getting response...

Let me know if have any question?

Thanks

Comment: I tried your script but it doesn't work for me at all, even if I put the "database process" before the "VERIDIED" test..

This is my script, maybe you will find a mistake :

http://pastebin.com/XFLuQKnG

I wrote in comment where the database process is working

Comment: You just have to use the new paypal script at https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4